# How to generalize Removal of " " or ' ' from comma separated values

Tags: c#, .net

I have Few Values in a file like :

> "SHOP_6ABC003","SHOP_6ABC002"

but this can also be represnted as

> 'SHOP_6ABC003,'SHOP_6ABC002'

or even with out any double or single quotes ,like:

> SHOP_6ABC003,SHOP_6ABC002

Now I am writing my code assuming it will be double quotes:

```
   String orderValue = "";
   orderValue = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Documents\File.txt");

   string[] orderArray = GetList(orderValue, SHOP_PREFIX);

            foreach (var item in orderArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }


private static string[] GetList(string fileText,string prefix)
        {
            string[] orderArray;
            String orderValue = "";

            orderValue = fileText.Replace(prefix, "");
            orderArray = orderValue.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('"')).ToArray();

            return orderArray;


        }
```

But the problem here is if some one provides singlequoted values or without quotes , I will get undesired output. Any way I can generalize the solution so it will be have in the same fashion when it's inside double quotes or single quotes or without any quotes?

Comment: You could have a look at this http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: Do I really need a third party library for this?

Comment: No, of course not, but why wouldnt you ?

Comment: Why should I add dependecy for the small snippet?(not taking its other aspects into consideration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a char array with the chars you want to trim?

```
char[] ch = { '\'', '"'};
orderArray = orderValue.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim(ch)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

var orderValue = fileText.Replace(prefix, "");
            orderArray = orderValue.Split(',').ToArray();

No need to trim again with "" or '